# Test for ActiveAdmin create/edit form - "Add New" record button for associated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, activeadmin

I have an ActiveAdmin form to create a new ActiveRecord object, and the form is capable of also creating records for one of the "main" model's `has_many` associations, i.e.:

```rb
class Car < ApplicationModel
  has_many :tires
end

class Tire < ApplicationModel
  belongs_to :car
end

# ... in ActiveAdmin "cars.rb" file...
ActiveAdmin.register Car do
  ...
  
  form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors
    f.inputs 'Car' do
      f.input :color
      f.input :doors, as: :number
      f.inputs do
        f.has_many :tires, allow_destroy: true, new_record: true do |t|
          t.input :type
          t.input :size
        end
      end
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

There is also some controller logic not listed here that properly creates, edits, or destroys these records, including Cars and Tires. When the form renders (let's say I'm creating a new Car), there is a button at the bottom that says "Add New Tire". Clicking it renders a sub-form on the page with two fields: "Type" and "Size". I've set up the controllers to save both the Car and its associated Tires when I submit the form. That all works.

I'm struggling with an automated test to ensure that clicking the "Add New Tire" button causes the sub-form to render. I've added a breakpoint after clicking the button and inspected `page.body` to see if the sub-form exists, but it doesn't seem to be there - I only see what looks like a template of the sub-form in the button's (really an `a` element) code. This is the part of my test code that fails:

```rb
click_link 'New Car'
fill_in('Color', with: 'Blue')
fill_in('Doors', with: 2)

click_link('Add New Tire') # Succeeds
fill_in('Type', with: 'All-Terrain') # Fails, can't find element
```

I've tried other ways to match on the first sub-form field, like xpath and css selectors, but it just can't find the field, and like I mentioned above, I don't see an instance of the sub-form being rendered if I inspect the page with `page.body`. I'm stuck - can anyone help me figure out what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

I got a tip that adding `js: true` to the test definition could help, and as it turns out, it did:

```rb
RSpec.describe Car, js: true do
  ...
end
```

Comment: This is because your page is dependent on JAvacript for inserting the form into the page. The default driver (rack test) doesn’t support JS - see https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#drivers

Comment: Yeah, I did a little more research after posting this answer and found that explanation. Makes perfect sense, AA is using Javascript to render a copy of the has_many form element whenever I click "New Tire". Thank you for the explanation!